# Google AppScript - How to skip certain columns[INDEXes] when setting values from an ARRAY

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I am new to coding.

I am trying to edit and set values from an entire row but want to skip certain columns, because there are formulas in it.

In short: I want to / have to keep track of sing-in and sign-out times, which then will be calculated in the spreadsheet but shouldn't be overwritten by the array. Is there a way to skip every 3rd "value"/index (as these are the columns which have the formulas)?

In fact I want to skip the columns: TOTAL, day1tot, day2tot, day3tot .... day14tot.

```
function editCustomerByID(id,customerInfo){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  const custIds = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getDisplayValues().map(r => r[0].toString().toLowerCase());
  const posIndex = custIds.indexOf(id.toString().toLowerCase());
  const rowNumber = posIndex === -1 ? 0 : posIndex +2; 

  Logger.log(customerInfo);
  ws.getRange(rowNumber, 2, 1, 8).setValues([[
                                              customerInfo.name, 
                                              customerInfo.total, 
                                              customerInfo.day1in, 
                                              customerInfo.day1out, 
                                              customerInfo.day1tot, 
                                              customerInfo.day2in,
                                              customerInfo.day2out, 
                                              customerInfo.day2tot   

                                            // UNTIL DAY 14     
                                            
                                         ]]);
return true;
```

Comment: sorry and thank you for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip columns, you can subdivide your range into individual ranges and implement conditional statements

**Sample:**

```
function editCustomerByID(id,customerInfo){
  ...
  var valueArray = [
                                              customerInfo.name, 
                                              customerInfo.total, 
                                              customerInfo.day1in, 
                                              customerInfo.day1out, 
                                              customerInfo.day1tot, 
                                              customerInfo.day2in,
                                              customerInfo.day2out, 
                                              customerInfo.day2tot   

                                            // UNTIL DAY 14     
                                            
                    ]
  var startColumn = 2;
  //loop through all values
  for (var i = 0; i < valueArray; i++){
  // filter out every 3rd value
    if((i+1) % 3 != 0){
      ws.getRange(rowNumber, (startColumn + i)).setValue(valueArray[i]);
    }
  }
return true;
```

- Note that the sample code above uses the method [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) instead of `setValues()`
- Performing multiple requests to set values to individual ranges is less efficient that setting all values at once within a single request, however in your case it is necessary since your desired value range is not continuos

Comment: ohhhh thats nice. thank you. thats more than i expected. I worked for 2 days. sliced and spliced ;))) I will try tomorrow. thank you so much for that hint (MORE then a hint ;)))

Comment: I still struggle due to a strange error-message (FIRST 2 DAYS are fine. but getting undefined in the total fields of day 3 and 4. ) before implementing it. (not your issue or caused by your code. therefore I "believe" YOU and mark it as helpful as respect for your offered time. thx

Comment: Maybe you can log `total`to see where the problem comes from?